# Firefox - How to use FireSSH opening an website through SSH

Tags: firefox, ssh

I want to use SSH to open an website using Firefox through FireSSH extension.
After configuration Account Manager in Tools -> Web Developver -> FireSSH 
[image]

After fill out SSH information to the Account Manager. The firefox open new Tab and displayed to me an Console screen:

[image]

So, How do I open an web URL through SSH which is configured in FireSSH ?

Answer (score 0):

Run [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) on the remote server to act as a proxy.  Then you need to forward a local port (using the settings in the Advanced tab of FireSSH) to your remote Squid installation. Finally, set your local machine to use the local port as a proxy.

By default, Squid listens on port 3128.  So forward local port 3128 to remote 3128, and set your proxy to localhost:3128 (or 127.0.0.1:3128).